# Gradle console says Build succesful, but with errors, and application does not run

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Ok, this is a weird error:

- The app was working fine a month ago, I needed to introduce a fix today and it was not running. In between the only difference I can think of is a few Android Studio upgrades. But other apps still work perfectly.
- The app can Clean Project, Rebuild Project, and Generate Signed APK, with no errors
- The problem comes up when I try to run or debug the app on emulator

  - Full gradle console and build.gradle at the bottom of the post
  - I dont get a 'choose device to run' window, it stops before
  - Build says BUILD SUCCESFUL, but also says 682 errors
  - In Gradle Console it prints a dependencies tree in ASCII
- Another thing: the generated APK can be installed on the emulator and works to perfection

Has anyone encountered such an error?

Thanks in advance!

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uy.com.hermes.tugentman.stecnico"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1007
        versionName "v1.0.07"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "Hermes_Tugentman_STecnico_7inch_$versionCode")
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.resValue "string", "app_ver", variant.versionName
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile files('libs/mapquest-android-sdk-1.0.5.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

**Gradle Console**

```
Executing tasks: [androidDependencies]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:androidDependencies
debug
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1@aar
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1@aar
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1@aar
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1@aar
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1@aar
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1@aar
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
... lines removed to fit SO post limit, they are all in this format, full file can be made available if someone need to see it ...
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1@aar
|    |              +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1@aar
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0@jar
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0@jar
+--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17@aar
+--- __local_jars__:F:\Dropbox\Workspaces\AndroidStudio\Tugentman_STecnico_v1\app\libs\mapquest-android-sdk-1.0.5.jar:unspecified@jar
\--- __local_jars__:F:\Dropbox\Workspaces\AndroidStudio\Tugentman_STecnico_v1\app\libs\mapquest-android-sdk-1.0.5.jar:unspecified@jar

debugAndroidTest
No dependencies

debugUnitTest
No dependencies

release
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1@aar
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1@aar
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1@aar
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1@aar
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1@aar
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1@aar
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1@aar
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1@aar
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1@aar
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1@aar
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1@aar
... lines removed to fit SO post limit, they are all in this format, full file can be made available if someone need to see it ...
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1@aar
|    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1@aar
|    |         |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1@aar
|    |              +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1@aar
|    |                   \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1@jar
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.0@jar
|         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0@jar
+--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.17@aar
+--- __local_jars__:F:\Dropbox\Workspaces\AndroidStudio\Tugentman_STecnico_v1\app\libs\mapquest-android-sdk-1.0.5.jar:unspecified@jar
\--- __local_jars__:F:\Dropbox\Workspaces\AndroidStudio\Tugentman_STecnico_v1\app\libs\mapquest-android-sdk-1.0.5.jar:unspecified@jar

releaseUnitTest
No dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.466 secs
```

Comment: Go to `View > Tool Windows > Terminal` and type `gradlew build`. You should able to see all the output during the build include the error messages.

Comment: Thanks Joshua! This is the last output lines. I have not changed anything related to Java, and other working projects have the same Java definition.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\JRE8 contains a valid JDK installation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Google the error. It seems it has been answered before on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks again Joshua, the JRE/JDK error is gone. And after the gradle build i get a BUILD SUCCESSFUL. But the error posted in the question is still happening. Any other ideas?

Comment: Does it still show errors in `gradlew build`?

Comment: No, no errors. This is the full terminal output: [link to dropbox file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jefhqdozr8fqx88/terminal.txt?dl=0). Thanks!

Comment: All the `Note` are errors, you should take a look at it. Also, is the generated apk the right one? Sometime, it use the cache instead because the new one cannot be built.

Comment: Ok. Will look at them one by one. What could have happened here? No changes where made to the project. Thanks a lot Joshua!

Comment: I mean you can try to add a character to a string to see if the generate apk is new or not.

Comment: Thats an amazing hint. You are right, maybe the APK is old code. Worst case scenario I will start a new project and copy/paste the code... Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```